# Html script tags after elements

Tags: javascript, html, browser

Say I have a piece of html with inline javascript like this:

```
<div id="myDiv">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var myElement = document.getElementById("myDiv");
    if(!myElement)
        throw "Invalid";
<script>

<div /> ...and so on
```

So I have a script tag surrounded by div tags and the script operates on a div declared before it.

Is this a browser safe/HTML standard way of doing things?

Comment: Just in case... `<div />` is not a valid markup

Comment: Inline javascript is not a good practice and must be used only with a good reason I think, but I don't think your code could fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this a browser safe/HTML standard way of doing things?

It's safe, yes. It's even [advocated by the Google Closure library engineers](http://groups.google.com/group/closure-library-discuss/browse_thread/thread/1beecbb5d6afcb41).

The more standard approach is to put all of your script together at the very bottom of the page, just before the closing `</body>` tag, as [advocated by the YUI folks](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html).

Putting them in *immediately* after the elements they act on leads to lots of little `script` tags strewn throughout your content markup, which isn't really ideal (particularly on large teams where the markup/content team and the scripting team may well be completely separate).

Conversely, putting all the script at the very bottom leads to the potential that *briefly*, you can have things on your page that the user can click (say), where you intend to handle that click in code, but the user manages to get there before the code hooks up the click event handler. It's a small window of opportunity, but it's there. To handle that, you have a couple of choices to mitigate it:

1. *Progressive enhancment*, where the click does something useful even without the script having hooked it, or
2. A small inline script (not a separate file) at the top of the page hooking the relevant event on `document.body` (assuming it's a bubbling event), where that small script either queues up the clicks and then distributes them when the main code arrives, or (and this is not so nice) shows a "just a sec, we're still loading" sort of message.

You're quite right to **not** do what used to be the standard practice of putting your scripts in the `head` and relying on "ready" style events. There's no need for that whatsoever if you control where your scripts go.

Comment: Good explanation.  I didn't know the standard approach was to move away from `head`.

Comment: Very detailed answer. Thank you

Comment: @KevinBowersox: Thanks. Yeah, it's been a slow burn, but the sooner we get the content in front of the user, the better their perception of performance is. Downloading scripts and such takes time. (Not a *lot* of time, but time.) The YUI team were seminal on this, I think, with the mantra: "Styles, content, scripts". Of course, if your thing is a web *application*, rather than a web *page*, you're probably better off with some kind of "Loading" window making the user wait until all is ready. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Typically, if you depend on elements in your document, you'll include all scripts at the bottom of the page (right before `</body>`). This has the added benefit of not blocking the rendering of the page.

Read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329807/benefits-of-loading-js-at-the-bottom-as-opposed-to-the-top-of-the-document).

Comment: True, in a lot of cases, but it is often more important to segregate pieces of functionality into siloed templates containing markup and the logic which operates on it

Answer (score 1):

it's better to insert script in end of document

Comment: True, in a lot of cases, but it is often more important to segregate pieces of functionality into siloed templates containing markup and the logic which operates on it