# How to control the order of JS and CSS files in Xpages themes for better performance and especial files like Handlebars and Less

Tags: optimization, less, httprequest, xpages, handlebars.js

I like to know if there is a way to control css and js resources order in XPages Themes or Custom controls. Two reasons for this:

**1. Performance**: Is well known that when you place js files before the closing body tag the render is faster for the user ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329807/benefits-of-loading-js-at-the-bottom-as-opposed-to-the-top-of-the-document)). I can do that placing a ***script*** tag at the bottom of the Xpage or custom control but if I do so I'll lost the huge performance adventages I got when I use the ***resource*** tag and then check **Application > Properties > Xpages > Performance > Use runtime optimized Javascript and CSS resources** (in the latter case, js files are placed in the head tag).

**2. libraries like Handlebars and Less:** using resources tags I can add js and css with **content-type text/css** or **application/x-javascript** but with libraries like Handlebars and Less (really useful libs) I need different content-type or attributes.

This question is mainly on performance because it already works using link and script tags in custom controls like this:

**Handlebars:**

```
<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  template content
</script>
```

**Less:**

```
<link rel = "stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="css/styles.less" />
<script src = "js/vendor/less-1.6.0.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

...but I feel a little dirty :)

Answer (score 1):

If possible try to use the non-blocking pattern for your JavaScript libraries. This should prevent performance problems:

```
<script>
   var s = document.createElement("script"),
   t = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];

   s.src="js/vendor/less-1.6.0.min.js";       
   t.parentNode.insertBefore(s, t);
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

```
<xp:script clientSide="true" type="text/x-handlebars-template" contents="template content">
   <xp:this.attrs>
      <xp:attr name="id" value="entry-template" />
  </xp:this.attrs>
</xp:script>


<xp:linkResource type="text/css" href="css/style.less" rel="stylesheet/less" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was trying to find a "server side way". Your suggestion seems interesting, but, client side, I would think in something like [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) or [curl.js](https://github.com/cujojs/curl). Do you think your suggestion with document.createElement("script") has some advantage vs these libraries?

Comment: @JohannEchavarria: I have updated my answer with two server-side examples. The advantage of the non-blocking pattern is that the browser is not blocked while loading the JS libraries (limit of max. 2 at the same time). The page is loaded first, which gives the user a better experience (The page us visible during loadding)