# Problems in submitting form data using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, ajaxform

i am new in ajax. i am aware to html,php. i want to do the CRUD operation in ajax. i have created a **two file**

1. index.php
2. insert.php as below.

when i click on submit button it submit data and inserted in database. But it resfresh the page. please suggest me that where i made mistake.

my code as below:

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ajax test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var frm = $('#contactForm1');
    frm.submit(function (ev) {
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                alert('ok');
            }
        });

        ev.preventDefault();
    });
</script>


</head>
<body>
<form id="contactForm1" action="insert.php" method="post">
 <label>Name</label><input type="text" name="user_name"><br>
  <label>Age</label><input type="number" name="user_age"><br>
   <label>Course</label><input type="text" name="user_course">
   <br>
   <input type="submit" name="sumit" value="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**insert.php**

```
<?php


$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "" ,"aj");

$name = $_POST['user_name'];
$age = $_POST['user_age'];
$course = $_POST['user_course'];




$insertdata=" INSERT INTO test3 (name,age,course) VALUES( '$name','$age','$course' ) ";
mysqli_query($conn,$insertdata);


?>
```

Comment: Add `return false;` after `ev.preventDefault();`

Comment: First of all put your entire js code in $(document).ready(function(){...}); and then let us know if any problem is there?

Comment: i have added this. but result is same. no change.

Comment: check in console if any error is there ?

Comment: The problem is solved when i added $(document).ready(function(){...}); . And also i forget to close <script> tag.  Thanks for help.   Now if i have to clear value of text box when data submitted and also i want to do CRUD operation than any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close the script tag

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Use when document is ready

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var frm = $('#contactForm1');
    frm.submit(function (ev) {
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                frm[0].reset();
                alert('ok');
            }
        });

        ev.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

> The ready event occurs when the DOM (document object model) has been
>   loaded. Because this event occurs after the document is ready, it is a
>   good place to have all other jQuery events and functions. Like in the
>   example above. The ready() method specifies what happens when a ready
>   event occurs.

Comment: Thanks @Aman Rawat. its work. Now if i want to add image upload and CRUD operations with this than please can you give me any suggestions.

Comment: And when i submit than data is inserted in DB but the fields not clear. so can you help that how to clear fields which value is submitted.

Comment: use `frm[0].reset();` on success

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript code, binding the event handler, is executed too early. The DOM is not fully loaded yet so the form can't be found. jQuery doesn't warn about this.

Either wrap your code in jQuery's on doc loaded method `$(function(){  /* code here */ } )`.

Or/and move your JavaScript to the bottom of your HTML. This is a preferred method. See [Benefits of loading JS at the bottom as opposed to the top of the document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329807/benefits-of-loading-js-at-the-bottom-as-opposed-to-the-top-of-the-document) for more details

Comment: I've added two solutions for you. Writing code on mobile is hard ;-p

Answer (score 0):

There is no mistake. Technically, its correct. It's just not fitting in your use-case.
It's default behaviour that page refreshes when user submits form.
You have two options:

1. Stop further execution when your ajax call is completed. You can do this by javascript by using `preventDefault` method. Then, use `return false`.
2. Change the submit button to normal button. In other words, don't submit form normal way. Give an id to normal button and call javascript function upon its click.