# Is a script in the footer "render-blocking"?

Tags: javascript, html, rendering

After discussing it with a colleague, we need an answer to the question: Is a script in the footer "render-blocking"? I mean, is any content showed to the user before the script is completely loaded?

Thank you

Comment: Yes it is blocking. However, the parts before ( the body) has already rendered

Comment: I would say that any JS which is not inline, or asyc/deferred, is render-blocking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [**Benefits of loading JS at the bottom as opposed to the top of the document**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329807/benefits-of-loading-js-at-the-bottom-as-opposed-to-the-top-of-the-document) - In addition jQuery might be better off at the top as other scripts could avail of it right away

Comment: @Fran I'm not sure they're the same. One is discussing the benefits, the other is asking for a definition.

Comment: @evolutionxbox - I thought it answered this question `If I put it in the footer, will rendering start before the script finishes downloading?`

Comment: _'If I put it in the footer'_ Do you mean the `<body>` here?

Comment: @JamesDouglas I have assumed OP meant, "before `</body>`".

Comment: @evolutionxbox Then what is OP's question, as he clearly states he knows the outcome when he puts it in the body.

Comment: @JohanKarlsson that is a better question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is coming late but I found the answer: No, a script is not render-blocking, a script is parse-blocking. Only CSS files are render-blocking.

If the script is inside the body, it will be parse-blocking but the content parsed before the script can already be rendered (if it is in the head nothing will be rendered because no content has been parsed yet). So, yes, content can be showed/rendered before the script is completely downloaded.

Please, see these two examples:

[Screenshot Test1: Content rendered before the large JS file finishes downloading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2FWq.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <section>
  <h2>testing</h2>
  <h4>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text printer took a galley of type and scrambled</h4>
  <img src="img/icon_128.png" width="128px" alt="">
  <h3>We are testing</h3>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesf own printer.</p>
 </section>
 <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Screenshot Test2: Content before the large JS file is rendered. The rest has to wait until the JS finishes downloading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhekE.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <section>
  <h2>testing</h2>
  <h4>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text printer took a galley of type and scrambled</h4>
  <img src="img/icon_128.png" width="128px" alt="">
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  <h3>We are testing</h3>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesf own printer.</p>
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you place javascript in the footer of the page; i.e. before the closing`</body>` without hte *defer/async* attribute then it is render blocking.

When the browser constructs the **DOM** and reads a script tag even in the footer and without the `defer/async` attribute, then, the browser can only continue the construction of the DOM if the script is completely downloaded.

Note that the **DOM** construction is not yet visible in the browser, until the browser paints the result.

#### The browser goes to 4 major steps before we can actually see the results.

1. DOM and CSSOM constructions.
2. Render Tree
3. Layout - computes the exact position and size of each object.
4. Paint - is the last step; renders the resulting pixels to the screen.

Links for [Removing Render-Blocking Javascript](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS) and [Render-tree Construction, Layout, and Paint](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/render-tree-construction)

Answer (score -2):

Generally, every script is a blocker, but it is better to hold js in the footer.

Html page is executed by browser line by line as like as your code. If your script will be in the footer - that means that everything that before this script - is already rendered.